# Convert CSV Scrape to mySQL insert

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script that is scraping a website into a csv file.  I am trying to convert it to an mySQL insert statement.  The code below is inserting NULL values into my table.  How can I alter it to work?

Note: the commented out lines are removing the CSV scrape that is working.

```
#f = codecs.open('results.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
d = date.today()
todays_date = date.strftime(d, '%m/%d/%y')
#f.write("Date,Time,Away)
#f.write('\n')

def scrape_game_info():
    all_tbodies = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
parsed_tbodies = [
    i for i in all_tbodies if 'ctl00_content_ctl00' in i.get_attribute('id')]
del parsed_tbodies[0]
dictionary = OrderedDict(itertools.izip_longest(
    *[iter(parsed_tbodies)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    tds = key.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    date = tds[0].text
    if date == todays_date:
         away=tds[2].text
         #f.write(date)
         #f.write(',')
         #f.write(time)
         #f.write(',')
         #f.write(away_rotation_number)
         #f.write(',')
pgp=("INSERT INTO pgp (Date, Time, Away)\
VALUES (date, time, Away)
cursor.execute(pgp)
```

**this is part of the code, but I believe enough to help define the issue.

Comment: Why don't load csv directly to mysql ?

Comment: Because I will be running this script often

Comment: I have GUI's people use that do `load data infile` every minute. In the place of your looper thing. Tremendously faster.

Answer (score 0):

I used Drew's suggestion to use load data infile.  I ran the script as normal which creates the csv.  I then added code that loads the data after the script was created.